# Tuleap: What does "Inconsistent Epics, User Stories" message mean on the Agile Dashboard

Tags: tuleap

In the Agile Dashboard, in one of the Backlog there is a section "Inconsistent Epics, User Stories" and a button "Add them to Current Backlog".  What does this message mean and what is the consequence of adding the artifacts to the backlog.

Answer (score 0):

The "inconsistent X/Y" means that some of the artifacts (stories or epics) where added as part of the sub backlog but not to the current one.

This happens when you add a story directly into a sprint backlog without adding it to the release backlog.

When you click on the button, it will just add the listed artifact in the backlog of the current milestone (ie. adding the stories in the release backlog in my example)